# How to record using Vuser Int, Action and Vuser End?

Tags: loadrunner

I'm a new beginner using the LoadRunner. Really need help to record `Vuser Int` for Login Process, `Action` for Register Process and `Vuser End` for Logout Process.

Firstly at Start Recording window, I change Record into action `Action` then click ok to start record the Login process. Then I'm confused either to click `Start` or `Pause` or `Stop` to start recording the Action for Register process. Can anyone guide me to use this features.

Answer (score 0):

Please read product documentation and attend training.  Your questions are addressed in both mediums.

Be curious.   Use your foundation skills in research.  Insist that your management follow a path of success which includes training and a period of internship to allow to you succeed in this role.

Answer (score 0):

When starting your recording, select the VUSER_INIT as the initial action to record into. Record your Login process here. Then switch to using the ACTION action for recording the actual process, and lastly switch to using the VUSER_END action when you do the Logout process.

*Tip: If your process is more complicated you may want to split it into several actions too. This can be done by creating a new action right from the recording toolbar shown during recording.*

*This way you will record your 3 separate processes into 3 separate actions.*

**Note**
Using the VUSER_INIT and VUSER_END actions in this way may lead to strange and difficult to handle situations. It is better to have actions for Login and Logoff that get called dynamically when needed in the actual script. The example cases below:

*Case 1*

If you want a new user to Login/Logoff every iteration you need to do the Login and Logoff processes inside each iteration instead of once in the beginning and end.

*Case 2*

Imagine a situation where you run your process over and over, and then suddenly something goes wrong and you need to do a Logoff and Logon (or switch user) to fix the process..